# Computing daily averages of multiple columns in Pandas Dataframe, then inserting a row with them

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I've inputted a CSV file using Pandas to a data frame and want to calculate the daily averages of the columns within it. There are 2 columns that won't be averaged, time and date (with the date being what the data is grouped together from). I then want to insert a row below the last row of that date, with 'Average' in the date column (nothing in the time column) and then the corresponding averages in the correct columns. I've only been using Pandas for a little while and so I'm unsure what the easiest way to go about this is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tables have fixed columns so making a second aggregate table and then merging with the new one is not something that's recommended. The average table should just be a separate table. If you were to actually add a row then you'll have an average column added to the table where it is NA in every row except the average row and the average row will have all other column as NA.

Comment: @MYousefi I think I will opt to do that and just make a separate table for averages. Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do what your question asks:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Date':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
'Time':[9,12,15,9,12,15,9,12,15,18],
'Col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
'Col2':[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
})
print(df)

df2 = df.drop(columns=['Time']).groupby('Date').mean().join(df[['Date','Time']].groupby('Date').count(), on='Date')
mx = df2.Time.max()
stepup = 10
while stepup <= mx:
    stepup *= 10

foo = []
for i, count in zip(df2.index, df2.Time):
    foo += [(i - 1) * stepup + y + 1 for y in range(count)]
df.index = foo
df = df.reindex(foo)
dataCols = [x for x in df.columns if x not in ('Date', 'Time')]
for i in df2.index:
    df.loc[i*stepup, ['Date'] + dataCols] = ['Average'] + list(df2.loc[i, dataCols])

df = df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True).fillna('')
print(df)
```

Explanation:

- Use `gropuby()` and `join()` to create a second dataframe `df2` to hold per-`Date` aggregate information, with one row per unique `Date` value containing the `count()` of original rows in each group in the column `Time` and the per-column `mean()` in each other column.
- Find the smallest power of 10 `stepup` such that the largest group above has fewer rows.
- Build a new index for the original dataframe that renumbers the elements in each group of like `Date` values such that index values equal to integral multiples of `stepup` fall between successive groups and are empty and available for us to use later (to insert the desired group summary rows).
- Iterate over `df2` to insert the information from each row at the appropriate index in the reindexed original dataframe.
- Sort the expanded dataframe by index, use `reindex()` to give it a new range index, and replace NaN with '' so the aggregate summary rows are more readable.

Note: This approach accommodates the formatting requirements of the question with the arguable trade-off that it's slightly inconsistent with the idea of having each column in a pandas dataframe have a homogeneous data type.

---

Input:

```
   Date  Time  Col1  Col2
0     1     9     1     9
1     1    12     2     8
2     1    15     3     7
3     2     9     4     6
4     2    12     5     5
5     2    15     6     4
6     3     9     7     3
7     3    12     8     2
8     3    15     9     1
9     3    18    10     0
```

Output:

```
       Date  Time  Col1  Col2
0       1.0   9.0   1.0   9.0
1       1.0  12.0   2.0   8.0
2       1.0  15.0   3.0   7.0
3   Average         2.0   8.0
4       2.0   9.0   4.0   6.0
5       2.0  12.0   5.0   5.0
6       2.0  15.0   6.0   4.0
7   Average         5.0   5.0
8       3.0   9.0   7.0   3.0
9       3.0  12.0   8.0   2.0
10      3.0  15.0   9.0   1.0
11      3.0  18.0  10.0   0.0
12  Average         8.5   1.5
```